Why dp doesn't work for android TV as expected?
I work on the screen for android TV (Jetpack Compose) implementation where (specifically) Card size looks differently for (emulator) 720p TV and 1080p TV
720:

1080:

Card code:
...
Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(412.dp)
                .height(200.dp),
            border = CardDefaults.border(border = Border.None),
            colors = CardDefaults.colors(
                containerColor = ColorTokens.grey_40,
                contentColor = ColorTokens.white,
                focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
                focusedContentColor = Color.Black,
                pressedContainerColor = Color.Gray,
                pressedContentColor = Color.LightGray
            ),
            shape = CardDefaults.shape (shape = RoundedCornerShape(CornerRadiusTokens.radius_300.withDPIOffset(LocalContext.current))),
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        )
...

I would expect Cards to looks the same for both screens since dp in use, what am I missing here?

What are the emulated screen sizes of your two emulator images? My guess is that you will find that the 1080p screen is larger.

@CommonsWare added an answer

@CommonsWare oh, I got what you mean, sorry for the confusion. Looks like the default emulator TV size is 55". However, in my case the problem was (as I described in my answer) that our design (in Figma) built for 1080p display only and sizes there in px. So, if say the UI item (in design) takes 200px, I just used this value as is in dp like - 200.dp, but it is not right to use pixel value as is in dp. So, I come with solution (descirbed below in the answer). Does it make sense?

@Sirop4ik: Personally, I do not fully understand your answer, but I had a mistake in my previous comment, which I have now deleted.

@CommonsWare in my comment above I meant that 200px != 200.dp

Finally, I got an idea, the problem is that our design was done for the screen 1080p with all the UI items values in px (not dp). It means that once you try to use let's say 200px for different screens obviously it would look different.
So, in order to support screens 1080p as well as 720p it is necessary to adjust sizes from 1080 to 720 screens
There is a function:
inline val Int.extToDp: Dp
    @Composable get() = with(LocalDensity.current) { this@extToDp.toDp() }

val Int.pxToDpWithOffset: Dp
    @Composable get() {
        val screenDensity: Float = LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi.toFloat()

        val factor: Float = when {
            screenDensity <= DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV -> {
                (screenDensity / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH)
            }

            else /* DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH */ -> {
                1f
            }
        }

        val adjustedDp: Int = (this * factor).roundToInt()
        return adjustedDp.extToDp
    }

Usage:
...
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(412.pxToDpWithOffset)
                .height(200.pxToDpWithOffset)
...

P.S.: Let me know if you see any ways for improvements
